# window.stop method does not seem to work when used within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

So ive been wracking my brains with this for a while but can't figure out why this isnt working.

Im setting up some simple functionality to prevent a user from leaving a page via hyperlink and instead displaying an overlay. So ive set up a simple event listener on all links which when clicked will stop page load and fire up the overlay.

The mmClickRecieved variable is for another part of the script and is just to ensure a user only ever sees this overlay once. The timeout function will fire the same overlay if the user is inactive on page for a certain period of time.

However when i try this code, when clicking a hyperlink the overlay fires fine but the page does not stop loading. Ive tried various bits of this code in isolation and it all seems fine, cant quite figure out why this is not working. Any ideas anyone?

```
$("a").click(function() {
    if (mmClickRecieved === false) {
      if (navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer") {
    window.document.execCommand('Stop');
      }
      else {
    window.stop();
      }
       clearTimeout(mmTimeout);
       mmNumberOverlay();
    }
    else {
        // no further action
    }
})
```

update: not sure why ive got a -1 for this.. I can update the question if it doesnt make sense

Comment: Why don't you simple use `event.preventDefault()` and then display the overlay? `window.stop()` _only_ works if the browser isn't actually loading another page. Its meant for stopping the load of _your_ current page, not preventing load of another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use `preventDefault` - it stops the user from following the link that was clicked and instead allows you to do something else with this click:

```js
var mmClickRecieved = -1;

$("a").click(function(event){
   // I am using this as an easy way to mimic your value
   if(!(++mmClickRecieved)){
     event.preventDefault();
     mmNumberOverlay();
   }
   // You don't need an else, since the event wont be prevented
})

function mmNumberOverlay(){
  alert("This happens only once!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Go to Google (this is not allowd in this snippet)!</a>
```

Comment: thats perfect, was completely unaware of this method! no wonder what i was doing seemed so overcomplex, thank you very much!